# Embedded In Person Signing process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

I've been trying like mad to get this to work, and I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm at a loss right now.

I'm using the SDK for DocuSign example.  I've modified it lightly to try to get an InPersonSigner embedded:

```
private Recipient[] ConstructRecipients()
{
    // Construct the recipients
        var runningList = new List<Recipient>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= Request.Form.Count; i++)
        {
            if (null !=Request.Form[Keys.RecipientName + i])
            {
                var r = new Recipient
                    {
                        UserName = Request.Form[Keys.RecipientName + i],
                        Email = Request.Form[Keys.RecipientEmail + i] // <-- Using my DocuSign account email for simplicity
                    };

                // Get and set the security settings
                string security = Request.Form[Keys.RecipientSecurity + i];
                if (null != security)
                {
                    //...Code still here, just making this post shorter
                }
            }
            // Try InPerson Signing
            r.RequireIDLookup = false;
            r.UserName = "AccountUserName"; //<-- Again, My Account user name for simplicity
            r.SignerName = Request.Form[Keys.RecipientName + i]; // "BB King"
            r.Type = RecipientTypeCode.InPersonSigner;

            r.ID = i.ToString();
            //r.Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer;

            if (null == Request.Form[Keys.RecipientInviteToggle + i])
                {
                    // we want an embedded signer
                    r.CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo {ClientUserId = i.ToString()};
                }
                runningList.Add(r);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return runningList.ToArray();
    }
```

When sending via email, it works, the Host (me) receives the Email, and is able to go through the "In Person Singing Process".

When sending for embedded results (remember I'm using the SDK out of the box for the embedded part - which includes ClientID), it errors with this message: "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."

What do I need to add to make the Embedded SDK sample work with a In Person Signing Session?

---- EDIT ----
I found the issue, but don't know the best solution.  Apparently, the GetStatusAndDocs.aspx.cs file has this line:

```
DocuSignAPI.FilteredEnvelopeStatuses statuses = client.RequestStatusesEx(filter);
```

Statuses contains an EnvelopeStatus object, and that contains a RecipientStatus object.  The RecipientStatus objects returns the UserName field as the SignerName that I entered, not the UserName that I entered.

This RecipientStatus object doesn't even have a SignerName property/field???  Why?

What property/field should I use to pass to the RequestRecipientToken username parameter?  If it's one of my field agents, I need to know how to fully identify the person and their account to determine they went to the field, fired up the app, and then did an in person signing.

Still at a lost although I have figured this out so far?

Comment: Which SDK are you using, the [DocuSign .NET client](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client)?  If so, how are you creating the envelope in the first place?  Are you setting the `clientUserId` for the recipient when they are first added to the envelope and referencing the same value when generating the signing URL?

Comment: Ergin - NO, not the .NET client.  I'm using the https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK.  It includes the clientUserId in the code line referenced in the original post (r.CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo {ClientUserId = i.ToString()};).  The SDK page handles the clientUserId.  Note I edited the response because I found where the error occurs, and why, but I don't know how to get around it.  I need the field agent USERNAME, EMAIl, etc (not the SignerName), to pass to the RequestRecipientToken().

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

For an embedded RecipientTypeCode.InPersonSigner, the email address can be bogus, fake, junk, etc., (as long as it's in email format "somethingdotsomething@someplacedotsomething.whatever").

When it's RecipientTypeCode.InPersonSigner, the username you pass to the RequestRecipientToken() is the Actual Account Holder userName.  Not the account that you may have given access to your main account as an Agent or someone part of a group, and not the signer/recipient name, but the account holder name that is on the account credentials being used for embedded signature.

The code on page GetStatusAndDocs.aspx.cs can be modified as follows to accomplish this:

```
    protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl CreateEnvelopeTable(DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus status)
    {
        var envelopeDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");

        int recipIndex = 0;

        foreach (DocuSignAPI.RecipientStatus recipient in status.RecipientStatuses)
        {
            var info = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("p");

            String recipId = "Recipient_Detail_" + status.EnvelopeID + "_" + recipient.RoutingOrder + "_" + recipient.UserName + "_" + recipient.Email + "_" + recipIndex++;

            info.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"javascript:toggle('" + recipId + "');\"><img src=\"images/plus.png\"></a> Recipient - " +
                recipient.UserName + ": " + recipient.Status.ToString();
            if (recipient.Status != DocuSignAPI.RecipientStatusCode.Completed && null != recipient.ClientUserId)
            {
                // For InPersonSigner, this will not work because the recipient.UserName needs to be the credentialed account actual user name, not the recipieint userName.
                //info.InnerHtml += " <input type=\"submit\" id=\"" + status.EnvelopeID + "\" value=\"Start Signing\" name=\"DocEnvelope+" + status.EnvelopeID + "&Email+" + recipient.Email + "&UserName+" +
                //    recipient.UserName + "&CID+" + recipient.ClientUserId + "\">";

                // In order to make this work for InPersonSigner, we need the envelope account (the credentialed account) userName instead of recipient.UserName
                // Get correct user name depending on recipient type
                string userName = (recipient.Type == RecipientTypeCode.InPersonSigner) ? status.ACHolder : recipient.UserName;

                info.InnerHtml += " <input type=\"submit\" id=\"" + status.EnvelopeID + "\" value=\"Start Signing\" name=\"DocEnvelope+" + status.EnvelopeID + "&Email+" + recipient.Email + "&UserName+" +
                    userName + "&CID+" + recipient.ClientUserId + "\">";
            }

            if (null != recipient.TabStatuses)
            {
                // Code here is the same, just making it shorter for this response
            }
            envelopeDiv.Controls.Add(info);
        }

        // Code between here and return is the same, just making it shorter for this response

        return envelopeDiv;
    }
```